# Latest transloadit js does not work with java

Tags: java, transloadit

I work on a Java web application and use Transloadit. Until http://assets.transloadit.com/js/jquery.transloadit2-v2.3.5.js it worked fine, but since http://assets.transloadit.com/js/jquery.transloadit2-v2.4.0.js is is broken. I have a normal html form:

```
<form action="http://api2.transloadit.com/assemblies" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

The Transloadit server receives the upload and, according to their server, sends a response back. I receive the response and try to read it:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

  StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
  String line = null;
  try {
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

According to Java there are no lines, thus Java thinks the body is empty.
But when I use Transloadit js version 3.5 Java does see the lines...

Are there other Java programmers who use Transloadit?

Comment: Did you check for any JavaScript / ajax errors? I know of a case where trouble like this caused partial Transloadit JS execution, leading (somehow) to an empty response.

Comment: Also, I noticed you are using `http://` and not `https://`. I think 2.4.0 will respect protocol now - which could mean you are actually downgraded to HTTP if you were defaulted to HTTPS before. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Yes I did check for javascript errors, there are none.
I tested using https, but this made no difference, I still get an empty response.